# Why does this cause a crash?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory

I have these two buttons hooked up to these two methods (they're nearly identical)

```
-(void)moveOneImageNewer{
    int num = [numberOfImage intValue];
    num--;

    numberOfImage = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",num] retain];

    //Load the image
    [self loadImage];
}

-(void)moveOneImageOlder{
    int num = [numberOfImage intValue];
    num++;
    numberOfImage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",num];

    //Load the image
    [self loadImage];
}
```

If I hit either of them twice (or once each, basically if they get called a total of two times) I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. If I throw a retain on:  `numberOfImage = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",num]retain]` it's fine though. Can someone explain why this is? I did an NSZombie on the instruments and traced it back to this stringWithFormat call. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that you **don't** want to do the `retain` every time unless you have matching `release` calls.  Failure to `release` will cause the strings to be "leaked".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

+stringWithFormat: doesn't contain 'new', 'alloc', 'copy', or 'retain', so it should be expected that you have to retain the return value of it if you want the new NSString it creates to stick around.

Edited to include this handy link duskwuff kindly dug up: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH

Comment: Here's the official Apple reference on retain/release rules: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH

Comment: I'm still kinda sticky on memory management, but isn't it autoreleased? and Wouldn't it make a new autoreleased variable every time I call it?

Comment: And the simple way to manage this is to make `numberOfImage` a retained property and do `@synthesize` for it.

Comment: Right, it's autoreleased.  But when are things autoreleased??  Basically, when the UI "comes up for air", which is after your action method returns.

Comment: bipolarpants: yes, it is autoreleased, which means it will be released once the current autorelease pool drains. Attempts to use it after that point will crash, as you're seeing.

Comment: Pretty much everything created through `[Object objectWith...:]` is autoreleased.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification for when it's released, but I'm confused as to why it's not creating a new autoreleased variable in memory every time it runs..?

Comment: It is. Why do you think it isn't?

Comment: ohh actually I get it, it's released when being called before the "string with format" is being called again. So it's pointing to nothing (I think?)

Answer (score 2):

If numberOfImage is a properly declared property, e.g.

```
@property (copy) NSString *numberOfImage;
```

and it was properly synthesized (in the @implementation section for the class):

```
@synthesize numberOfImage;
```

then you can do:

```
- (void) moveOneImageNewer
{
    self.numberOfImage = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i", [self.numberOfImage intValue] - 1];

    // Load the image
    [self loadImage];
}
```

The property setter will take care of retaining the string and, if necessary, releasing the previous string.

FWIW, why on earth is numberOfImage a **string**? Why not a simple int?

Comment: I need it to append to a URL, hence the need to chance it to a int, change the number and then convert it back into a string

Comment: Why not turn it into a string when you need it, and not before? If it is an URL and you want to append the num, simply use `stringWithFormat: @"%@%03d", [URL path], num`, assuming num is the int property.

Comment: Just curios, what am I accessing if I leave off the self.? It crashes unless you add it.

Comment: @bipolarpants: as I said, if you leave of `self.`, you access the ivar directly. If you use `self.numberOfImage`, you use the getter and setter the compiler synthesizes for you, and the setter will take care of copying (which also means retaining) the string and releasing the previous string. IOW, properly declared and synthesized properties will manage the retain and release for you.

Answer (score 0):

numberOfImage is an instance variable or property of your class, right?

You are setting it to a `stringWithFormat` (which returns an auto-released NSString) without claiming ownership of that object (by calling retain).

If you do not retain it, it will get auto-released before the method is called again (and then the first line will fail, as it tries to access the previously set, now auto-released value).

Consider using properties, they have auto-generated memory management code (including releasing the old NSString when you set the new one).

Answer (score 0):

Well, the NSString class method "stringWithFormat" returns an autorelease NSString object if I'm right.

So the second call to your method would have numberOfImage pointing to nothing, as the autorelease NSString object it used to be pointing to has already been released and deallocated since you didn't retain it.

The part that is directly causing the crash is `[numberOfImage intValue]` when you call the method a second time, as you sending a message to an object (pointed to by numberOfImage) that no longer exist.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't retained the string object in "moveOneImageOlder", so that object gets autoreleased at the end of the event cycle and points to nothing. That's why you get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS next time you try to use it.

Use a retain to claim ownership of the NSString. Remember to release when you're done though (you can use properties to help you with this)

```
-(void)moveOneImageNewer{
    int num = [numberOfImage intValue];
    num--;

[numberOfImage release];
    numberOfImage = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",num] retain];

    //Load the image
    [self loadImage];
}

-(void)moveOneImageOlder{
    int num = [numberOfImage intValue];
    num++;
[numberOfImage release];
    numberOfImage = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",num] retain];

    //Load the image
    [self loadImage];
}
```

Add this in dealloc:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [numberOfImage release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```